# Trying to center text from proportional font on TTGO T5 ESP32 in C

Tags: c

I created a font binary file from a TTF file and I can place it on the TFT screen on the TTGO T5 T-Display just fine.  Looks great!  I have been looking for 2 days for how to center this information on screen.  I cannot find the format of the .vlw file or the format of what I included in the sketch to print from (converted by online site from .vlw format).  And I can't find a routine to do it for me.

I am using the TFT_eSPI and it does not contain a getTextBounds routine.  There is one in the Adafruit_GFX library and I included that but it not available any way I have tried.  And I can't read it enough to fix it for what I need.  Too deep for me at this time, especially since I don't know the data file format.  I have been programming for decades but can't make this stuff up!

So, simple question with a complex answer, it seems.  How to center a proportional font (invoked by name (not one of the numbered default fonts) on TTGO TFT screen using ESP32.

This makes my brain hurt.  Help, please...

Comment: you might want to start with the [true type file format](https://docs.fileformat.com/font/ttf/)